# how to display images inline using css in bootstrap?

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> MyBLOG </title>
<head>


 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap_costumize.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

 <script src="css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <div class="navbar-brand"> This is a Logo </div>
         </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" >
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>   
         </ul>

   </nav>

        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
         <div class="img">
           <img src="img/blog_picture_1.jpg" />
         </div>
         <div class="img">
       <img src="img/blog_picture_2.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="img">
       <img src="img/blog_picture_1.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="img">
       <img src="img/blog_picture_2.jpg" />
       </div>
     </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

this is the php code and this display the image top to bottom how can i display the images inline like from left to right?

im struggling also how to connect css selector in img and div hehe can sum1 pls elaborate the methods shoud i do thank you :)

Comment: Either don't wrap them in divs, or give the divs the appropriate grid class.

Answer (score 0):

Since your images are all wrapped in `div`s with `.img` class, write the following in your CSS.

```
.img { display: inline; }
```